# Group windows in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac

Is there a way to group 2 or more windows so that they act together? If I drag one, they all move. If I hide one, they all hide. If I alt-tab to one, they all come in focus, etc.

These windows might be in different applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do believe I understand what you are requesting, and actually find it very interesting. However, this functionality does not exist in the **base OS** itself (10.5.x | 10.6.x | 10.7.x). An alternative to grouping windows in OS X, that you be interested in, is to utilize Mission Control (10.7) and Expose. In **Mission Control** you can add a new Desktop and drag your window(s)/Applications into that new Desktop thereby grouping them. They do not have to be like items and this can be done a number of times. Expose does not really cover what you have requested, but still is beneficial in terms of grouping **like** items.

Comment: That might work. Then I would be switching Desktop to different tools rather than cmd-tabbing through them, yes?

Comment: @Drew That is correct. :–)

Comment: @Drew have you found that Mission Control successfully does what you were wanting?

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen [Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/)? I've never used it so I can't comment from experience, but the features list in the Mac App Store states:

> Windows can STICK TOGETHER

So, it might have the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Optimal Layout does window switching and movement, not what is being asked here.